# My Samsung phone just keeps restarting

Tags: samsung, reboot

I have never been in a situation like this. I was developing some widget app on my Samsung A12 with Android 12 and all of a sudden, while building and running the app, the system just shut off. It restarted, then after I typed the PIN code, while trying to load the home screen, it does it again. Then it loads again, this time it shuts off just in the lock screen.
And it keeps doing this forever. I cannot even shut it down, I tried hard booting it with volume down and power button but it only goes as far as to the home screen (after PIN). It restarts again

This phone has a few months, it is not rooted, battery is at 70%, never did this to me before. I was setting an attribute for a widget `android:maxResizeWidth="@dimen/widget_min_width"`, then when testing it this started happening.

I am watching the wretched thing doing restart after restart. Is there anything I can do before trying to remove the (unremovable) battery?

*New info*: I managed to get in Safe Mode and it looks like it works, so it's some app, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. First, that Samsung is the worst at developing software.

Secondly, yes, indeed, using `android:maxResizeWidth="@dimen/widget_min_width"` sent One UI into a crazy coma. I had to remove the app and rebuild it without that line